# AutoMapper with CreateMissingTypeMaps and AddProfile

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using the AutoMapper with Profiles and it is working very well. Recently, I found the CreateMissingTypeMaps configuration and, if it is working like I understand, will make my development faster, one time that will not be necessary create simple mappings.

I have added to my configuration a Profile with AddProfile and, after that, I did the CreateMissingTypeMaps configuration.

Ex:

------- Creating configuration ------------

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
 {
     cfg.AddProfile<PersonServiceMapperProfile>();
     cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
 });
```

------- Inside my PersonServiceMapperProfile ------

```
internal class PersonServiceMapperProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<PersonData, ProfileViewModel>().ConvertUsing<PersonDataToProfileViewModel>();
    }
}
```

When the CreateMissingTypeMaps configuration is set to true, the Profile not works anymore. My custom mapping is not called.

How to solve this question?

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: @Brad I just upgraded from v3.3 to v6, and it's happening to me.  I'm trying to figure out how I get away from using DynamicMap in so many places that I don't need to bother with a CreateMap (I would literally have 100 or so empty calls to CreateMap).  I'll post back here when I figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue after upgrading from AutoMapper 3 to 6 recently, and I found an Issue in GitHub for AutoMapper that revealed the solution to this problem:

> The AddConditionalObjectMapper() is the way to go so your anon types are mapped but not overwrite your default mappings. Don't use that with CreateMissingtypeMaps, because that overwrites the condition. CreateMissingTypeMaps basicly is AddConditionalObjectMapper().Where((s, d) => true);

[Source: Issue 2008, TylerCarlson1](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2008)

**However, this should not be used for "simple mappings".**  The CreateMissingTypeMaps feature is intended only for use when the mappings are not known until compile time, such as with EF Dynamic Proxies.  The reason it shouldn't be used for known types is because the CreateMap and compilation features allow you to quickly test against and prevent failed mappings due to typos, mismatched names, new or removed properties, etc etc.  It's a big deal to use the compilation feature as intended, so make the most of it.